# confusion with dereferencing argv

Tags: c, console-application, argv

I have this small program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
   printf("argv[1] -> %s\n", argv[1]); 
}
```

Which I analyzed in `gdb` with the following commands:

```
$ gdb -q  --args foo hello
Reading symbols from foo...
(gdb) break main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x1148: file foo.c, line 5.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /tmp/foo/foo hello

Breakpoint 1, main (argc=2, argv=0x7fffffffea68) at foo.c:5
5          printf("argv[1] -> %s\n", argv[1]);
(gdb) print argv@2
$1 = {0x7fffffffea68, 0x200000000}
(gdb) print *argv@2
$2 = {0x7fffffffecd8 "/tmp/foo/foo", 0x7fffffffece5 "hello"}
```

I don't understand how `argv[1]` can yield the string `"hello"` when the content of `argv[1]` is 
`0x200000000` and not `0x7fffffffece5` which is the actual address of the string `"hello"`.

Answer (score 0):

`print argv@2` doesn't do what you think it does. Instead of printing `argv[0]` and `argv[1]`, it appears to print `(&argv)[0]` and `(&argv)[1]`.

Here's what I got when I tried debugging your program:

```
(gdb) p argv
$1 = (char **) 0x7fffffffecd8
(gdb) p argv[0]
$2 = 0x7fffffffeeb8 "/home/a.out"
(gdb) p argv[1]
$3 = 0x0
(gdb) p argv@2
$4 = {0x7fffffffecd8, 0x100000000}
(gdb) p (&argv)[1]
$5 = (char **) 0x100000000
```

Comment: Why isn't the second number in `argv@2` located `sizeof(char***)` bytes after the first one then?

Comment: @bool3max `argv@2` prints the values of `argv` and of the non-existent pointer located right after `argv` in memory, not their addresses.

Answer (score 0):

I used the examine command in `gdb` and now things make sense:

```
(gdb) x/2xg argv
0x7fffffffea58: 0x00007fffffffecc2      0x00007fffffffecd5
(gdb) x/1s 0x00007fffffffecc2
0x7fffffffecc2: "/tmp/foo/foo"
(gdb) x/1s  0x00007fffffffecd5
0x7fffffffecd5: "hello"
(gdb)
```